# HTML Button Jumping to anothers page bottom not working

Tags: php, html, forms

i am trying to jump on a button click from a HTML page to the end of a PHP page.
This is an excerpt of my code

HTML Page:

```
<form method="post" action="page.php#bottom">
...
submit button...
</form>
```

PHP Page:

```
<HTML>
<body>
...
<div id="bottom"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I press the button, I am redirected to the php.page, but not to the bottom. Whats the fault? Or is there any other solution?

Thank you in advance

Comment: @RiggsFolly Is there any other way to trigger the jump by a button press?

Comment: Pass a param like `<form method="post" action="page.php?goto=bottom">` and in the page write a bit of javascript to jump to that id in the poage

Comment: @RiggsFolly
I am learning HTML/PHP so i got no clue from JS, you got any source I can learn to code the jump?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams

Comment: @RiggsFolly sure you can, that is just an anchor in a URL - not significantly different from putting this into the `href` of a link.

Comment: Oh ok, learn something new every day @CBroe